# Translate Pseudocode into python

Tags: python, pseudocode

Below is the pseudocode to calculate an adaptation of the Levenstein minimum distance. I have the first part decoded for python but I can't figure out the bottom part, denoted with ***.

Algorithm of distance calculation (pseudocode) using dynamical programming:

```
First Part:

int function distance(Sequence sequence1, Sequence sequence2)
  set length_1 to length of sequence1
  set length_2 to length of sequence2

declare distances[length_1+1][length_2+1]

for i from 0 to length_1
  set distances[i][0] to i

for j from 0 to length_2
  set distances[0][j] to j

// Classical Levenshtein part
for i = 1 to length_1
  for j = 1 to length_2
    set cost to 0
    if (sequence1[i-1] not equal to sequence[j-1])
      set cost to 1
    set distances[i][j] to minimum of
          distances[i-1][j-1] + cost,// Substitution
          distances[i][j-1] + 1, // Insertion
          distances[i-1][j] + 1 // Deletion

set min_distance to distances[length_1][length_2]

******New Part- Help!*******
// Truncating
for i from 0 to length_1
  set min_distance to minimum of min_distance and distances[i][length_2]
// Elongating
for j from 0 to length_2
  set min_distance to minimum of min_distance and distances[length_1][j]
return min_distance
```

Comment: instead of sharing the pseudocode for the first part, why don't you share the code?

Comment: But that's the same operation as the 'Classical Levenshtein part' isn't it? Iterate through a line of the two-dimensional array and compute the minimum of some values?

Comment: sorry guys i'm a rookie and i realized my translated code was messed up anyways. Could one of you save my life and translate the whole pseudocode into python. The most important thing is the last part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return min(itertools.chain((x[length_2] for x in distances),
  distances[length_1]))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Ignacio...I guess I translated the first part differently. would you be so kind as to translate the whole pseudocode? You would be a life saver, im trippin out!